# AWK If pattern not found in one out of two similar lines, print line with pattern found

Tags: regex, bash, awk

Good day,

**Problem**

There are two lines, the field separator is comma. Therefore, each line have 6 fields.

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr
abc,def,ghi,jkl,,pqr
```

**Target**

If field five is empty, don't print that line.

**Expected Output**

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,pqr
```

**So far I have done**

`awk '{print ($5=="")?:$5}'` file

Thank so much in advance for giving me any clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F',' '$5!=""' file
```

.......

Answer (score 2):

It can be much simpler:

```
awk -F, '$5' file
```

i.e. print any line which has non-empty `$5`.

Comment: That's not all that script will do. Try it if $5 has the value 0 or 0.0 or 0e3 or anything else that awk will decide has the numeric value of zero.

Comment: You are right. But OP appears to have to strings only. I initially thought similar to yours but decided this is simpler. +1 to yours too!

Comment: It appears to be only sample data OP shows. So no guarantee that there are no `0` etc in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Two more awks,which wont break if field just contains 0.

```
 awk -F, '$5~/./' file
 awk -F, 'x!=$5' file
```